# Magento view is not showing proper prices

Tags: magento, view

This file (frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml) was edited, now is not showing the proper prices, 
http://www.personalproducts4u.co.uk/hotel-toiletries/au-lait

I changed the third table tag (ONLY THE THIRD TABLE TAG)on the file above AND THE PRICES ARE SHOWING ALL THE SAME (ON DISCOUNTED PRICES)
any ideas?

this is the code I changed:(pasted it on the third table tag of the lists file)

```
 <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="buy_heading">Buy</th>
                        <td class="buy_pay_content">1</td>
                     <?php 
                            /*foreach($tierPrices as $key=>$value) 
                            {
                                echo "<td class='buy_pay_content'>".number_format($tierPrices[$key]['price_qty'],0)."</td>";
                            } */
                        ?>
                        <?php
                     if(count($tierPrices)):
                     foreach($tierPrices as $key=>$value) 
                          {
                              echo "<td class='buy_pay_content'>";
                              echo number_format($tierPrices[$key]['price_qty'],0);
                              if($key == $count-1) 
                              {
                                    echo "+";
                              }
                              echo "</td>";
                          } 
                     else:
                    echo '<td class="buy_pay_content">5</td>
                     <td class="buy_pay_content">10+</td>';
                     endif; 

                      ?>
                        <td class="buy_pay_content">Quantity</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="pay_heading">Pay</th>
                        <td class="buy_pay_content"><?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?><?php //echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice()) ; ?>

                        <?php //echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice()) ; ?> <?php //echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true)

                         ?>
                        </td>
                       <?php 
                       $specialprices = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialPrice(); 
                       if($specialprices)
                       {
                           $specialprice =$specialprices; 
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           $specialprice = 0;
                       }
                         if(count($tierPrices)):
                            foreach($tierPrices as $key=>$value) 
                            {
                                if($specialprice < $tierPrices[$key]['price'] && $specialprice != '0'):
                                //echo 'special less'.$specialprice;
                                ?>
                                <td class='buy_pay_content'><div class="price-box"> 
                                      <p class="old-price"><span id="old-price-182" class="price"> <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($tierPrices[$key]['price']) ?> </span>  </p>
                                      <p class="special-price"> <span id="product-price-182" class="price"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($specialprice) ?></span></p>
                                   </div></td>
                                <?php
                                else:
                                ?>
                                <td class='buy_pay_content'><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($tierPrices[$key]['price']) ?></td>
                                <?php
                                endif;
                                ?>


                            <?php } 
                            else:
                                echo "<td class='buy_pay_content'>".$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true)."</td>";
                                    echo "<td class='buy_pay_content'>".$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true)."</td>";
                            endif;
                        ?>

                        <td class="buy_pay_content"><input type="text" class="input-text qty" title="Qty" value="" maxlength="12" id="qty" name="qty"></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the issue seems to be the fact that getSpecialPrice() returns what ever is in the Special Price field. I could be mistaken but I don't believe you can supply special tiered prices in Magento. You can still add a static special price but as you have already experienced it will display the same price for each iteration.

You will probably need some sort of custom extension or template logic to display such sales properly.

I am not sure how you currently manage your tiered pricing, but if it is a fixed percentage for each tier you could set your tiered prices to the calculated sale prices and calculate and display the original tier prices by dividing each tiered discount percentage and display that number.